# Making a Digital Signature field Read only

Tags: aem, designer

I am designing a form in AEM designer 6.3 where are 3 digital Signature fields in sequence 1,2,3. Initially when form loads, fields 2 and 3 are locked. 2 gets unlocked only when  field is digitally signed. In similar manner 3 gets unlocked only after 2 gets signed.

Am not able to lock signature fields. I have tried with following codes:

field.access = "protected"
field.readonly = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At initialization of form, lock the field 2 and 3 with

field2.access  = "readOnly"
field3.access  = "readOnly"

In postsign event of Field1, unlock field 2 with following code
field2.access  = "open"
Repeat the same for feild 2.